# regex to match all subfolders of a URL, except a few special ones

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, edgecast

OK, I'm writing a regex that I want to match on a certain url path, and all subfolders underneath it, but with a few excluded.  for context, this is for use inside verizon edgecast, which is a CDN caching system.  it supports regex, but unfortunately i don't know the 'flavor' of regex it supports and the documentation isn't clear about that either.  Seems to support all the core regex features though, and that should be all i need.  unfortunately reading the documentation requires an account, but you can get the general idea of edgecast here: https://www.verizondigitalmedia.com/platform/edgecast-cdn/

so, here is some sample data:

```
help
help/good
help/better
help/great
help/bad
help/bad/worse
```

and here is the regex I am using right now:

```
(^help$|help\/[^bad].*)
```

link: https://regex101.com/r/CBWUDE/1

broken down:

```
( - start capture group
^ - start of string
help - 1st thing that should match
$ - end of string
| - or
help - another thing that should match
\/ - escaped / so i can match help/
[^bad] - match any single character that isn't b, a, or d
. - any character 
* - any number of times
) - end capture group
```

I would like the first 4 to match, but not the last 2, 'bad' or 'bad/worse' should not be matches, and help/anythingelse should be a match

this regex is working for me, except that help/better is not a match.  the reason it's not a match, i'm pretty sure, is because better, contains a character that appears inside 'bad'.  if i change 'bettter' to 'getter' then it becomes a match, because it no longer has a b in it.

so what i really want is my 'bad' to only match the whole word bad, and not match any thing with b, a, or d in it.  I tried using word boundary to do this, but isn't giving me the results i need, but perhaps i just have the syntax wrong, this is what i tried:

```
(^help$|help\/[^\bbad\b].*)
```

but does not seem to work, the 'bad' urls are no longer excluded, and help/better is still not matching with that.  I think it's because / is not a word boundary.  I'm positive my problem with the original regex is with the part:

[^bad] - match any single character that isn't b, a, or d

my question is, how can i turn [^bad] into something that matches anything that doesn't contain the full string 'bad'?

Comment: Use [`^help(?:\/(?:(?!bad).)*)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/3jpx2t/1), or better, `^help(?:\/(?!.*bad).*)?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jpx2t/2))

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i think the syntax in the accepted answer is cleaner and also works so i accepted that one

Comment: It is just different, not cleaner nor dirtier. It depends on what your requirements are. Yours are not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use negative look ahead (?!bad) instead of negating specific letters [^bad]

I think (^help$|help\/(?!bad).*) is what you're looking for

Edit: if you mean anything with the word bad at all, not just help/bad you can make it (?!.*bad.*) This would prevent you from matching help/matbadtom for example. Full regex: (^help$|help\/(?!.*bad.*).*)